# Tornado, how to drop POST/GET with 401 if a token is not provided

Tags: python, tornado

I want to drop GET/POST requests if a token field is not provided in the headers.

Currently I use [this code (from GitHub Gist)](https://gist.github.com/Integralist/18ef92e020b6dcb074f49d799f4cc67f):

```py
def require_basic_auth(handler_class):
    def wrap_execute(handler_execute):
        def serve_error(handler, status):
            handler._transforms = []  # necessary
            handler.set_status(status)
            handler.finish()

        def _execute(self, transforms, *args, **kwargs):
            expected_header = self.request.headers.get('X-User-Auth')

            if expected_header is None:
                return serve_error(self, 403)

            kwargs['token'] = expected_header
            # Token validation is done in the `post(self, token)` method

            return handler_execute(self, transforms, *args, **kwargs)

        return _execute

    handler_class._execute = wrap_execute(handler_class._execute)

    return handler_class
```

Two problems:

1. It patches a `_method`, and I'm a bit uncomfortable manipulating methods whose names begin with a `_`
2. It causes Uncaught Exception error: `AttributeError: '_NullFuture' object has no attribute 'add_done_callback'`

Reading a bit, I see that the `.prepare()` method might be the best way to implement this. But I haven't found any examples on how to do this properly in `.prepare()`.

Can someone show me an example on how to do this?

---

#### Edit 1

I forgot to add: The decorator above also conveniently extracted the header into a `token` kwarg to be consumed by the `post(self, token)` method. I'm not sure how to do that if using `prepare(self)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, directly patching Tornado's `RequestHandler` is not ideal.

With Tornado, you're supposed to create a base class for your handlers. This base class acts like a "middleware" as seen in other frameworks (Django, Flask, etc.)

Another pattern with Tornado is to create "mixin" classes which is useful for plugging in common features to specific handlers.

This is what I do in my projects:

```py
class BaseHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        expected_header = self.request.headers.get('X-User-Auth')
        
        if not expected_header:
            return self.send_error(401)

        # ... other common logic to run before other methods ...


# Inherit your handlers from BaseHandler everywhere
class MyHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Heyy, that's a good idea, making mixin classes! Thanks, nice example as well!